# How to use unicode in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, unicode

I am using CI framework for my project. If I use like this

```
$title= "प्रदेश";      // प्रदेश is written in nepali langauge.

echo $title;        // It will display प्रदेश
```

Now I want to use

```
<a href = "<?php echo base_url("home/$title")?>">    //home is a controller
```

Now In home controller if I tried to display`$title` it will not show प्रदेश.

It will display like this `%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B6`

**Please help me.**

Comment: try using charset utf-8 in meta tag .. i

Comment: Why are you using `$title` in url? Your title should go inside `<title>` tag. The result is URL encoded and it's absolutely ok.

Comment: Looks like uri encoded. Try: <?php echo base_url("home") . "/" . $title ?>

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI I am processing `$title` in controller.

Comment: @LeszekRepie yes it is uri encoded and not working

Comment: @KrityShrestha - what does it mean "processing $title in controller" and "not working"? Show us your code that is not working (probably your controller).

Comment: url is displayed like this `localhost/lm/home/प्रदेश` but if I tried to output `$title` in controller then no `प्रदेश` is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base_url calls [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on the string, which makes it into url entities.
A space becomes %20 and things like that.

The url that is displayed is actually correct and should be interpretted correctly by the server, even if it's gibberish according to humans.

If you really want the human readable characters for some reason you can do two approaches, [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) the resulting url(not recommended):

```
echo urldecode(base_url("home/$title"));
```

or

```
echo base_url("home/").$title
```

Comment: A big Thnks. I use `urldecode($title)` and I can get `प्रदेश` in my controller. Superb